# One property of a class calling another class' prototype method

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, prototype

Coming straight to the code, here's the `Player` class.

```js
class Player {
  constructor(pos, speed) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  get type() { return "player"; }

  static create(pos) {
    return new Player(pos.plus(new Vec(0, -0.5)),
                      new Vec(0, 0));
  }
}

Player.prototype.size = new Vec(0.8, 1.5);
```

And the `Vec` class:

```js
class Vec {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
  }
  plus(other) {
    return new Vec(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
  }
  times(factor) {
    return new Vec(this.x * factor, this.y * factor);
  }
}
```

I just can't seem to understand this:

```js
return new Player(pos.plus(new Vec(0, -0.5)),
                   new Vec(0, 0));
```

Where's `pos.plus()` is coming from?

`plus()` method is in the prototype of `Vec`, right? How can `pos` have access to `plus()`? It's a property of `Player` class, but calling the method of `Vec` class. I'm confused. Need some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are being confused by variable scope. The `pos` argument passed to the constructor of `Player` is only visible in the constructor itself, although it can also be accessed on the instance since the constructor sets `this.pos`. However, in the `create` method, `pos` is an entirely different method parameter that has nothing to do with the `pos` in the constructor.

Comment: I see. Never noticed that part. My bad.